# spf record setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, exim, spf, email-server

Emails sent by mta from my server recognizes by spam filters as spam and there's message :
**Received-SPF: neutral ...**

Actually, I am not spammer :)

So, I googled around these questions and found that I need setup two things

1. SPF record
2. DKIM

Now I am trying to correctly setup and tune on server SPF record.

So, I did already:

a. added spf record to domain hosted zone on amazon.

It's something like this :

**"v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:ip_adress_where_from_i_send_mail -all"**

b. checked spf record through spf query lib and also through spf checker http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

spfquery --scope mfrom --id noreply@mydomain.com --ip ip_adress_where_from_i_send_mail

Result :

**Received-SPF: pass**

c. setup on server domainname, it was empty, maybe this is useless action, not sure

sudo domainname mydomain.com

but now i get in exim logs :

```
[4:11:23 PM] Sergey Glazyrin: 
2012-09-29 17:08:15 1THwmF-00086h-2Y <= noreply@mydomain.com U=www-data P=local S=847 id=b1e267a45af62b2132fe36125b00e1ed@mydomain.com
2012-09-29 17:08:15 1THwmF-00086h-2Y aspmx.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4001:c02::1b] Network is unreachable
2012-09-29 17:08:16 1THwmF-00086h-2Y => dev@mydomain.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=aspmx.l.google.com [173.194.70.27] X=TLS1.0:RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1:16 DN="C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=mx.google.com"
2012-09-29 17:08:16 1THwmF-00086h-2Y Completed
```

And I am not sure what to check/do now ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the problem is. It looks like everything's working. The logs say there's some outgoing email, it tries to connect to `aspmx.l.google.com` via IPv6, it fails so it tries to connect via `173.194.70.27` and is successful, and the last line says it's finished.

Comment: but my emails still are in spam in google mailboxes. and there's message when I see original : **Received SPF: neutral**. And I think this is one of the reasons why my email in spam. It looks like exim don't want to check SPF domain record although I enabled needed flag **CHECK_RCPT_SPF = yes**
btw, thx for your answer! this is a first answer to my question on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @SergeyGlazyrin **Received SPF: neutral** is fine. If google blocked for a not-bad-not-good SPF response, 99% of all legit emails not from google would get blocked. SPF is checked by the receiving MTA, to check if the IP that the email is being received from is allowed to send for the envelope From address. Your Exim would be checking SPF for its incoming email.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jon Lin's answer, you can get rid of the message.  Disable ipv6 in your exim build or disable it at runtime by adding to the global options in your exim.conf:

```
disable_ipv6 = true
```